Using for loop in openxlsx to copy down formula -- more efficient method ideas?
Currently using the following structure and syntax to copy down a formula in openxlsx workbook.
for(i in 1:10){
  writeFormula(wb, tab_name, paste0('SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,A',i',), startRow = i, startCol = 1)
}

This sort of syntax and structure ultimately accomplishes what I want, which is to copy a formula down a defined cell range but looping over the rows gets slower and slower
Trying to see if there are more efficient ways to iterate writeFormula() down a column without the for loop.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think the syntax of this has unmatched quotes and would fail to parse: paste0('SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,A',i',). It's not clear what the goal is. I'm wondering why one wouldn't use paste0('SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, A', i+(0:9) ) without any need for a loop.

Here's an example of using paste0 to construct a vector of characters that has an increasing index without using a for loop and placing that vector in a worksheet with a descending placement within a column:
library(openxlsx)
?writeFormula
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", x = iris)
writeFormula(wb, sheet = 1, x = paste0("A", 10+0:9), # 10 items 
                            startCol = 10,           # put in the "J" col
                            startRow = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb, "writeFormulaExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

Result (using LibreOffice):

BTW, the idea of gaining efficiency by using apply instead of for(...) was doomed to failure since apply is just a wrapper around for. The days when for-loops were inefficient are long gone, probably 15 or 20 years since that was a thing. (I can't even remember which one was held in low repute, since they were equivalent since before I started using R in 2008. What's inefficient is failing to use vectorized functions to replace line by line algorithms.

I wish there were a pithier way to communicate the reality of the "loops are slow" situation. Loops in R are fast, it's the touching the data afresh at every step that is slow...

This will work great, thank you! And agree it sounds like it is a somewhat prevalent myth about apply > loops for efficiency, or at least it used to be.
